# PHP imap_close($conn) provokes 301 redirect

Tags: php, redirect, imap

It looks like I disabled DKIM on cpanel on a VPS linux server, and today, all scripts I have that uses PHP imap, started to return 301 redirect.

Those scripts have no redirects coded on them, after debugging line by line, it turns out that the line that closes the imap connection "imap_close"  is the one provoking the script to make a 301 redirect.

Any clues? anyone? please?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the setting back DKIM as it was, made the imap_close work again (after some hours). Strange, but that is what happend.